# Change storage folder when create zip

Tags: php

I use this code to create ZIP file from PHP
ZIP is correctly created, but I have a little trouble when download zip.

On browser, ZIP name appear like this

```
.._.._storage_temp_2013-09-03-1378245354.zip
```

I'm like to mantain only

```
2013-09-03-1378245354.zip
```

Here code I use:

```
$files = array($frente, $verso);
//$zipname = '../../storage/file.zip';
$zipname = "../../storage/temp/".date('Y-m-d')."-".time().".zip"; // Zip name

$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $new_filename = substr($file,strrpos($file,'/') + 1);
    $zip->addFile($file,$new_filename);
    //$zip->addFromString(basename($file),  file_get_contents($file));
}
$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($zipname)
```

Comment: This code has nothing to do with generating the file download for the browser. You should show that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved in this way:

```
$new_zipname = substr($zipname,strrpos($zipname,'/') + 1);
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$new_zipname);
```